# When would you use the "thread-id" key in your push payload?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I am working on updating an app's notifications and I was looking through the documentation around the push payload and I saw the `thread-id` key. In the documentation it says:

> Provide this key with a string value that represents the app-specific identifier for grouping notifications. If you provide a Notification Content app extension, you can use this value to group your notifications together.

I'm not totally sure what they mean by `grouping your notifications together`.

What is a use case for this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thread-id** is used when you have different parts of your app that you send pushNotifications say you have a transportation app , one group may be for handling trip states another group for offers and discounts so you want them same thread-id notifications to be grouped , but you have to implement a a Notifictation UI extension for it to be shown in group as apple's default way is conversation , see more here [thread-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009738/ios-thread-id-doesnt-group-push-notifications)